# RAM problems while creating and deleting custom QWidgets inside of QLayout

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ram, qwidget

I have created a custom `QWidget` (code below) [with a `QHBoxLayout` and two `QPushButtons` inside] and added it to a `QVBoxLayout` in GUI. This custom `QWidget`-object will be created and deleted several times (code below).

When I type `top` inside into the console (on embedded linux) there is a RAM-increase every time I add a new `QWidget`. That's Ok! But I can't see a decrease of RAM on deletion.

What is wrong with my code? I want, that the RAM decreases on deletion of the custom `QWidgets`.

myCustomWidget.h

```
class QCustomPushButton_withinIcon_LeftAndRight : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    //functions
    QCustomPushButton_withinIcon_LeftAndRight(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~QCustomPushButton_withinIcon_LeftAndRight();

    //other slots like:
    // - virtual void mousePressEvent();
    // - virtual void mouseReleaseEvent();
    //other signals like:
    // - void clicked();
    //other functions like:
    // - virtual void setEnabled(bool a);
    // - virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
    // - ...

private:
    //variables
    QLayout *innerLayout;           //!< Layout for two buttons
    QPushButton *buttonLeft;        //!< Button left
    QPushButton *buttonRight;       //!< Button right

    //other variables like:
    // - bool enabled;
    // - ...
};
```

myCustomWidget.cpp

```
QCustomPushButton_withinIcon_LeftAndRight::QCustomPushButton_withinIcon_LeftAndRight(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    mSVG (new svg),
    mGradient (new gradient)
{
    enabled = true;

    //create innerLayout
    innerLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
    this->setLayout(innerLayout);

    //create buttons
    buttonLeft = new QPushButton();
    buttonRight = new QPushButton();
    innerLayout->addWidget(buttonLeft);
    innerLayout->addWidget(buttonRight);

    //create connections like:
    // - connect (buttonLeft, SIGNAL(pressed()), this, SLOT(mousePressEvent()));
    // - ...

    //set some stylesheets
    // - buttonLeft->setStyleSheet("...");
}
QCustomPushButton_withinIcon_LeftAndRight::~QCustomPushButton_withinIcon_LeftAndRight()
{
    //I think, that this is right. If not, correct me.
    delete buttonLeft;
    delete buttonRight;
    delete innerLayout;
}

//void QCustomPushButton_withinIcon_LeftAndRight::mousePressEvent() {}
//void QCustomPushButton_withinIcon_LeftAndRight::mouseReleaseEvent() {}
//void QCustomPushButton_withinIcon_LeftAndRight::setEnabled(bool a) {}
//void QCustomPushButton_withinIcon_LeftAndRight::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) {} ...
```

gui.cpp (add `QWidgets` to a `QLayout` in the GUI)

```
    QCustomPushButton_withinIcon_LeftAndRight *button = new QCustomPushButton_withinIcon_LeftAndRight();
    //add button to layout
    parentUiWindow->aLayoutNameInGui->addWidget(button);
    //aLayoutNameInGui is type of QVBoxLayout
```

gui.cpp (delete `QWidgets` in a `QLayout` that is in the GUI)

```
    //delete all buttons in layout
    QLayoutItem *child;
    while((child = parentUiWindow->aLayoutNameInGui->layout()->takeAt(0)) != 0) {
        //parentUiWindow->aLayoutNameInGui->removeWidget(child->widget()); //already removed by ->takeAt()
        //child->widget()->setParent(NULL);
        delete child->widget();
        delete child;
    }
```

Comment: I'm sure there must be a few duplicates around regarding this issue. But the "problem" is most likely that the operating system doesn't have to unmap the allocated memory pages from your process when you `delete` or otherwise free memory. Instead it can do it at any time it feels like. That means those pages will seem like a memory leak. It's a false positive.

Comment: It would be easier to read and replicate your code if you put the function declarations in your code instead of "gui.cpp (add QWidgets to a QLayout in the GUI)"

Comment: I see you create `mSVG` and `mGradient` with `new`, but do you destroy these objects anywhere?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude are you really shure? That would be great if it is true.

Comment: @thuga I tried, to delete them to.. app does actually better after that

Comment: @thuga I think, that this was actually the problem. Great thanks :) just write an answer (refer to `someprogrammerdude`: he has a important point to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at the memory usage with the `top` command, you can get false positives. As stated by *some programmer dude*, the OS doesn't always release the allocated memory from your process when you call `delete` on some objects.

However, you are creating two objects in your `QCustomPushButton_withinIcon_LeftAndRight` constructor with `new`:

```
mSVG (new svg),
mGradient (new gradient)
```

but you never seem to destroy these objects. So you might have a memory leak there.